# Retrieve input value from Jquery UI dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I am working on a small project (just a practice example - not for real use). Its a very simple CRUD application, and I am not aloud to alter the index.html. Also have to use JQuery UI Dialog and not prompt().

I got up to ADD functionality and I'm stuck. I've created a Jquery UI dialog that appends a form - its triggered when 'Add item' is clicked. Then The action for clicking 'yes' in the form needs to return what was in the input. I am unable to retrieve the value and there is no server side technology(like php)involved. **function add_item()** in answers.js is where I am working now.

I also don't know why, but an additional input box appears on the bottom of my html page after clicking 'Add item' (it should only append to the form )

*Note: CRUD functions begin after document.ready...lower on the page.
Also, besides the one default item in index.html **list items are originally from a json file**
*

### answer.js

```
   $(document).ready(function()
    {

///////// REMOVE ALL  ////////////
    $(document).on("click", "div a:nth-of-type(3)", function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        remove_all();
    });
    $("div a:nth-of-type(3)").click(remove_all);

    ///////// ADD ITEM  ////////////
    $(document).on("click", "#add_item", function(e)
    {
          e.preventDefault();
          add_item();
    });
    $("#add_item").click(add_item);

///////// LOAD ALL ////////////
        $(document).on("click", "div a:nth-of-type(2)", function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            load_all();
        });

///////// REMOVE ITEM  ////////////
        $(document).on("click", "#my_list a", function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            var current_item = $(this).parent();
            remove_item(current_item);
        });
        $("#my_list a").click(remove_item(current_item));

///////// EDITABLE ITEM  ////////////

});

/// CRUD FUNCTIONS ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function add_item()
{

$('body').append('<div id="dialog-form"><form> Add your item:<br><input type="text" name="new_item" id="new_item" ></form></div>');

//  JQUERY UI DIALOG
  $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    resizable: false,
    title:'Add new item',
    height:240,
    width:260,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Yes": function() {
        var test = $('#new_item').val();
         alert(test);

        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    }
  });

}

function remove_all()
{
      $('#my_list li').hide();
}

function load_all()
{
        $.getJSON( "myLists/myList.json", function( json )
        {
            var items = json;
            $('#my_list li').remove();

            $.each(items, function(index,the_item)
            {
              $('#my_list').append('<li>'+the_item+'<a href="#">x</a></li>')
            });
        });
}

function remove_item(current_item)
{
        // APPEND DIALOG BOX DIV
        $('<div id="dialog-confirm">').appendTo('body');

        // JQUERY UI DIALOG
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
          resizable: false,
          title:'Remove this item?',
          height:140,
          width:260,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {
              $(current_item).hide();
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel: function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
          }
        });
  }
```

### INDEX.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link href="jquery-ui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="answer.js"></script>
    <title>jQuery Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>My Shopping List</h1>
        <a href="#" id="add_item">Add Item</a> | <a href="#">Load List</a> | <a href="#">Clear List</a>
        <ul id="my_list">
            <li>Brand New Shoes <a href="#">x</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To clarify, what are you getting here:  `alert(test);`

Comment: What does your `alert()` say?

Comment: The alert box opens, but there is no text displayed.

Comment: I don't see a restriction on calling add_item() more than once, which means you could potentially have more than one element with the same id (and that's not valid).  This probably isn't causing your problem (although it could result in unexpected behavior), but you should re-work your structure and use classes instead.

Comment: Also, the basic premise of getting the value from your dialog is working fine.  See here:  [JS Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tpwx8oex/)

Comment: Yeah, I just don't really see that the issue is. var test = $('#other_item').val(); not an appropriate way to try to get the value?

Comment: That's an appropriate way to get an input element's value, assuming you only have one element on the page with that id.  You can see from the demo link I posted, that structure works fine and returns the value of the input.

Comment: Hmm, I saw your example but I actually hadn't noticed you changed the code to log the variable and that it does work. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Offering a few updates that I think might help:

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/5g72nncw/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  ///////// REMOVE ALL  ////////////
  $(document).on("click", "div a:nth-of-type(3)", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    remove_all();
  });
  $("div a:nth-of-type(3)").click(remove_all);

  ///////// ADD ITEM  ////////////
  $(document).on("click", "#add_item", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Running Add Item.");
    add_item();
  });
  $("#add_item").click(add_item);

  ///////// LOAD ALL ////////////
  $(document).on("click", "div a:nth-of-type(2)", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    load_all();
  });

  ///////// REMOVE ITEM  ////////////
  $(document).on("click", "#my_list a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var current_item = $(this).parent("li");
    remove_item(current_item);
  });
  //$("#my_list a").click(remove_item(current_item));

  ///////// EDITABLE ITEM  ////////////

});

/// CRUD FUNCTIONS ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function add_item() {
  if ($("#dialog-form").length == 0) {
  console.log("Dialog not found, creating new Dialog.");
    var newDialog = $("<div>", {
      id: "dialog-form"
    });
  } else {
  console.log("Dialog Found.");
    var newDialog = $("#dialog-form");
    newDialog.dialog("open");
    return true;
  }
  newDialog.append("<label style='display: block;'>Add your item:</label><input type='text' id='new_item' />");
  //$('body').append('<div id="dialog-form"><form> Add your item:<br><input type="text" name="new_item" id="new_item" ></form></div>');

  //  JQUERY UI DIALOG
  newDialog.dialog({
    resizable: false,
    title: 'Add new item',
    height: 240,
    width: 260,
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: [{
      text: "Yes",
      click: function() {
        var test = $('#new_item').val();
        console.log(test);
        $("#my_list").append("<li>" + test + " <a href='#'>x</a></li>");
        $(this).dialog("close");
        $('#new_item').val("");
      }
    }, {
      text: "Cancel",
      click: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        $('#new_item').val("");
      }
    }]
  });
  //$("body").append(newDialog);
  newDialog.dialog("open");
}

function remove_all() {
  $('#my_list li').remove();
}

function load_all() {
  $.getJSON("myLists/myList.json", function(json) {
    var items = json;
    $('#my_list li').remove();

    $.each(items, function(index, the_item) {
      $('#my_list').append('<li>' + the_item + '<a href="#">x</a></li>')
    });
  });
}

function remove_item(current_item) {
  // APPEND DIALOG BOX DIV
  $('<div id="dialog-confirm">').appendTo('body');

  // JQUERY UI DIALOG
  $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    title: 'Remove this item?',
    height: 140,
    width: 260,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Yes": function() {
        $(current_item).hide();
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

When removing an item, you want to pass the `<li>` to your function. This way it is removed from the `<ul>`.

When adding the item, I did not append the `<div>` to the `body`. I noticed when you appended the `<div>`, since it was not in the DOM when the page loaded, it does not get initialized as a `.dialog()` and thus is rendered into the HTML. My method avoids this.

Nothing wrong with the way you create the buttons, yet this is more specific and is how it is described by the UI API: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wound up re-writing the program since I was having issues, but thank you for sharing this fix.